# How do I get the program to print the number of times a number occurs in the list?

Tags: python, list, element

This is as much as I know how to do, not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
L = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4 ]

n = len(L)
element = ()


if element in L:
    print(element)

print("number occurs in list at the following position, if element not in list")
print("this number does not occur in the list")
```

How do I go about getting elements that appear more than once, to print as

```
4 occurs in L at the following positions:  [0, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4]
>>> [i for i,x in enumerate(L) if x==4]
[0, 2, 6]
```

`enumerate(L)` gives you an iterator over `L` that yields a tuple `(index, value)` for each element of `L`. So what I'm doing here is take each index (`i`) if the value (`x`) equals `4`, and construct a list from them. No need to look at the length of the list.

Comment: so I don't have to use the length of the list?

Comment: It's worth noting that to display this information for all the elements, you can loop over ``set(L)`` (avoiding showing the each item multiple times as sets don't store duplicates).

Comment: @Lattyware well I thought that I would have to use the index for the number in the list.

Comment: @neonlights That sentence doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @neonlights That's what `enumerate` does - it loops over an iterable, and returns an auto-incrementing count (which can be used as the index) and the value of that element. It's an oft-used function - it's worth reading the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The compulsory `defaultdict` post:

```
from collections import defaultdict

el = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4 ]
dd = defaultdict(list)
for idx, val in enumerate(el):
    dd[val].append(idx)

for key, val in dd.iteritems():
    print '{} occurs in el at the following positions {}'.format(key, val)

#9 occurs in el at the following positions [4]
#10 occurs in el at the following positions [1]
#4 occurs in el at the following positions [0, 2, 6]
#2 occurs in el at the following positions [3]
#5 occurs in el at the following positions [5]
```

Then `dd` can just be used a normal dict... `dd[4]` or `dd.get(99, "didn't appear")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` to count distinct element in list, then use list comprehension to find the index of each element: -

```
>>> l = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4 ]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count = Counter(l)
>>> count
Counter({4: 3, 9: 1, 10: 1, 2: 1, 5: 1})

>>> lNew = [[(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(l) if x == cnt]  for cnt in count]
>>> 
>>> lNew[0]
[(4, 9)]
>>> lNew[1]
[(1, 10)]
>>> lNew[2]
[(0, 4), (2, 4), (6, 4)]
>>>
```

In fact you don't need `Counter` here. You can just get off with a `Set`

Create a Set of the list with the factory function : - `set(l)` and then you can do the same with it..

Comment: Do not use `is` for equality comparison!

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_repeated_elements_positions(L):
    for e in set(L): # only cover distinct elements
        if L.count(e) > 1: #only those which appear more than once
            print(e, "occurs at", [i for i, e2 in enumerate(L) if e2 == e])


L = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4]
print_repeated_elements_positions(L)
# prints: 4 occurs at [0, 2, 6]
```